# perl on windows stuck on calling for usleep from another module

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, usleep

I'm using the following perl code on windows environment:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);

    #(some code here)

$self->{GLOBAL_OBJ}->xsleep($delay) if($delay);


sub xsleep {    
    my $seconds = shift;
    #print "will sleep:$seconds seconds\n";
    $seconds = $seconds * 1000000;
    usleep($seconds);
    #print "slept:$seconds micro seconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I call xsleep like that (from another module) the system is stuck and I can only stop it by ctrl+c, however when I call it from the current module it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: If you are going to sleep in units of seconds, why not just use sleep (second resolution)?   You may also need to accept the param as `my ($self, $seconds) = @_;` in the first line of your xsleep subroutine.

Comment: thanks @xxfelixxx, it was the $self issue.

Answer (score 1):

`xsleep` is being called as a method, which means the invocant (the result of the left side of `->`) is passed as the first argument. This is currently ending up in `$seconds`. References numify to their address, so you get an extremely large numbers in `$seconds`. For example,

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say(0+{})'
9304720
```

Either adjust `xsleep` so it can be called as a method,

```
$self->{GLOBAL_OBJ}->xsleep($delay) if $delay;

sub xsleep {    
    my $self    = shift;
    my $seconds = shift;
    ...
}
```

or call `xsleep` as a sub

```
The::Package::xsleep($delay) if $delay;

sub xsleep {    
    my $seconds = shift;
    ...
}
```